# Browser compatibility JQuery UI selectmenu

Tags: jquery-ui, browser, opera, opera-presto

I'm using `jQuery UI - v1.11.4 - 2015-03-11`.

And it works on Chrome(`42.0.2311.135 (64-bit)`) and Mozilla(`37.0.2`), but `jQuery selectmenu` breaks on Opera 12.16 as it uses old engine called `Presto`.

Is there any information about compatability with Opera and the ways to get it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jquery [supports](https://jquery.com/browser-support/) Opera 12.1x

I tried this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gxtpc/475/) and I didn't face any issue when running.

```
$(function(){            
    $('select').selectmenu();
});
```

Comment: strange engine. now works fine - can't even guess  what happened to get it worked. anyway thank you